# retrieving specific rows from a table and storing each row as an associative array in session

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, arraylist, session-variables

I am creating a PHP/MSQL Application which is basically an online quiz, user will start quiz, internally for an instance randomly 30 questions are retrieved from db-table and stored in session. My database table has **qid, question, op1, op2, op3, op4, ans, category** as columns (as every question should have 4 options and one answer).
I want to retrieve all(for an instance 30) **question** stored in the table of an specific **category** and save them in session variables as 2/3-dimensional associative array using some loop say while()/for() etc.

The script i've written yet is,

```
session_start();
require 'connection.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='$category'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$found=mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());
if ($found!=0) {
    $i="1";
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='$category'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($que= mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $i<=$found) {
        $_SESSION["$i"]= array(
                                "question"=>$que['question'],
                                "op1"=>$que['op1'],
                                "op2"=>$que['op2'],
                                "op3"=>$que['op3'],
                                "op4"=>$que['op4'],
                                "ans"=>$que['ans']
                                );
                  $i++;
                 }
        echo $_SESSION["$i"]; // echo-ing some session variable
}
mysql_close($dbc);
```

**I had also used the script given below for achieving the same thing earlier but there was no success-**

```
session_start();
    require 'connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='$category'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $found=mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($found!=0) {
        $i="1";
        $result1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $_SESSION['que'][][]=array();
        while ($que= mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) && $i<=$found) {
                $_SESSION['que'][$i]['question']=$que['question'];
                $_SESSION['que'][$i]['op1']=$que['op1'];
                $_SESSION['que'][$i]['op2']=$que['op2'];
                $_SESSION['que'][$i]['op3']=$que['op3'];
                $_SESSION['que'][$i]['op4']=$que['op4'];
                $_SESSION['que'][$i]['ans']=$que['ans'];
            $i++;
            }
            }
    mysql_close($dbc);
```

**Finally i could do this using below code-**

```
session_start();
        require 'connection.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='$category'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $found=mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($found!=0) {
            $i="1";
            $result1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while ($que= mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) && $i<=$found) {
                    $str="que".$i;
                    $_SESSION[$str]['qno']=$i;
                    $_SESSION[$str]['question']=$que['question'];
                    $_SESSION[$str]['op1']=$que['op1'];
                    $_SESSION[$str]['op2']=$que['op2'];
                    $_SESSION[$str]['op3']=$que['op3'];
                    $_SESSION[$str]['op4']=$que['op4'];
                    $_SESSION[$str]['ans']=$que['ans'];
                    $_SESSION[$str]['opt']="0";
                $i++;
                }
                }
        mysql_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Why do you do the same query twice? What's the problem you're having with your script?

Comment: Do you call `session_start()`? You can't save session variables without this.

Comment: i think this script is not setting the session variables correctly... and yes i"ve already called session_start() above in the code...

Comment: How do you know they're not being set? What does the script that tries to read the session variables look like?

Comment: I want to retrieve n tuples from a table (6 fields per tuple) and store the values into session variables at server, I require n*6(say n=30 then 30*6=180) variables for that, It'll be cumbersome for me to do it manually, so i decided to do this using while loop, i tried to do this writing script i've posted above.. Can somebody help me reaching my goal.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your while loop, that's the normal way to process the results of a query. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: If all fine with my while loop, how can i echo the session variable '$i' ?

Comment: `$_SESSION[$i]` is an array, you can't echo it. Try `var_dump($_SESSION[$i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this to try.

```
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='$category'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$found=mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());
if ($found!=0) {
$i=1;
$sql= "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='$category'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($que= mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $i<=$found) {
    $_SESSION[$i]= array(
                            "question"=>$que['question'],
                            "op1"=>$que['op1'],
                            "op2"=>$que['op2'],
                            "op3"=>$que['op3'],
                            "op4"=>$que['op4'],
                            "ans"=>$que['ans']
                            );
    }
    print_r($_SESSION[$i]);
    $i++;
}
mysql_close($dbc);
```

Comment: @Yogesg Suthar- Why are you deleting my edit, again and again... what's your problem please mention it !!!!

Comment: @Hirdesh-Technonimal don't edit my answer. If you want to edit , edit your question.

Comment: If there's a problem with his answer, say so in a comment.

Comment: This is the result of this edit-
Array ( [question] => [op1] => [op2] => [op3] => [op4] => [ans] => ) Array ( [question] => [op1] => [op2] => [op3] => [op4] => [ans] => )